# How to use crypt(3) in windows?

Tags: c, windows, unix, mingw, crypt

How can I invoke crypt(3) from a c program on a windows platform? I can't find a header file to include. I have MinGW with gcc and msys installed.

Edit: as an alternative, I would also accept a way to call this function (or an equivalent) from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this?  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/crypt/

I suppose you may be missing it, or just don't realize you have it, but it seems like the answer, and I found it by typing "crypt mingw" into Google.

Comment: If you have the MSYS/crypt "dev" package, it should come with a "crypt.h" header file for you to include.